# Passing variable into function to create JSON body for JIRA

Tags: python, variables, label, jira

Python Code:

```
def jira_create(
    project,
    summary,
    description,
    components,
    issuetype,
    labels,
    reporter="valid_user_name",
    assignee="__unassigned",
    epicname=None,
):

    jira_url = "valud_jira_url"

    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}

    body = {
        "fields": {
            "project": {"key": project},
            "summary": summary,
            "description": description,
            "components": [{"name": components}],
            "issuetype": {"name": issuetype},  # EPIC, BUG, STORY, TASK
            "labels": [labels],
            "reporter": {"name": reporter},
            "assignee": {"name": assignee},
        }
    }

    print(body)

    jira_request = requests.post(
        jira_url + "/rest/api/2/issue/",
        json=body,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(jira_user, jira_pass),
        headers=headers,
    )

    print(jira_request.content)
    return

    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    jira_user = "valid_user"
    jira_pass = "valid_pw"
    
    project = "Project"
    summary = "testMe - Text - More Text"
    description = "Here's some text"
    components = "Project - Some Text"
    issuetype = "Epic"
    labels = "text1"
    # labels = "text1", "text2"
    reporter = "valid_user_name"
    
    jira_create(
        project,
        summary,
        description,
        components,
        issuetype,
        labels,
        reporter,
    )
```

Here is the JSON created from the Python code to be used with JIRA rest API 2:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "Project"
        },
        "summary": "testMe - Text - More Text",
        "description": "Here's some text",
        "components": [
            {
                "name": "Project - Some Text"
            }
        ],
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Epic"
        },
        "labels": [
            "text1", 
            "text2"
        ],
        "reporter": {
            "name": "valid_user_name"
        },
        "assignee": {
            "name": "__unassigned"
        },
    }
}
```

In the example JSON code above for the element 'labels', when a Python variable is a string with only one item, it passes correctly and the JIRA is created.
For example in the python code, when `labels = "text1"`, everything works (class 'str')

However, if passing two elements in the string `labels = "text1", "text2"`, this is where it fails (class 'tuple').

I have tried passing the items as a tuple, list, and set without much luck.

What is required for the JSON body is:
`'labels' = ["text1", "text2"]`

What occurs in the output is the following:

`'labels': [('text1', 'text2')]` (class 'tuple') note extra parentheses

result:

```
"errors": {
        "labels": "string expected at index 0"
    }
```

`'labels': [['text1', 'text2']]` (class 'list') note extra brackets

result:

```
"errors": {
        "labels": "string expected at index 0"
    }
```

`'labels': [{'text1', 'text2'}]` (class 'set') note extra braces

result:

```
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried converting labels without success:

```
labels = str(labels)[1:-1] > results in "contains spaces which is invalid"
labels = ", ".join(labels) > results in "contains spaces which is invalid"
labels = ", ".join(map(str, ("text1", "text2"))) > results in "contains spaces which is invalid"
labels = json.dumps(labels_multiple).replace("'[", "").replace("]'", "")
```

Is there a way for this to be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do something like:

```py
def jira_create(labels):
    if isinstance(labels, str):
        labels = [labels]

    body = {"labels": [*labels]}
    return body


body = jira_create("text1")
print(body)

body = jira_create(("text1", "text2"))
print(body)


""" Prints:
{'labels': ['text1']}
{'labels': ['text1', 'text2']}
"""
```